# Useless attribute after creating dual-line item layout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-xml

After creating a dual line list item layout, a warning appears. Does anyone know what can be done in order to resolve this warning and prevent the layout from containing anything 'useless'?

> This 'RelativeLayout' layout or its 'LinearLayout' parent is useless

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dip"
        android:layout_marginEnd="6dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dip"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/item_station"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary" />

        <TextView android:id="@+id/item_zone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/item_station"
            android:layout_alignStart="@id/item_station"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorSecondary" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This warning is being generated because there's no need for you to use your `<LinearLayout>` as a root element. You could just remove it and the warning should go away.

I mean, the `<LinearLayout>` has only one child, which is your `<RelativeLayout>`, so actually, the `<RelativeLayout>` is the one doing the heavy lifting here, and it could work as a root element.

Android Studio uses `lint` for checking your code for bugs and optimizations. It detected that "useless" usage of the `LinearLayout` and showed it to you.

You can read more about `lint` [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/tools/help/lint.html).